# Product Images Low Quality After Updating From WP 3.5 to 4

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I recently updated my WP website from WP 3.5 to recent version 4 and now I am getting a lower quality of all product feature images. I am using woocommercee to generate an online shop and it was working perfectly(HD thumbnails image qualities), I also updated the woocommerce plugin but still getting low quality images on the products

Can you please let me know why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woocommerce has their image [thumbnail regenerator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin offered in the settings. This should fix the image issue (did the trick for me).